# how to to return null if none selected in a method?

Tags: java

For example

```
private ArrayList<Book> books;
private int indexOfSelected;
```

I'm not sure if setIndexOfSelected() is correct, but it's supposed to set the index into the list of selected books.

```
public void setIndexOfSelected(int indexOfSelected) {
books.set(indexOfSelected, getSelectedBook());
```

and I need this method to return null if no book was selected, I'm not sure how to continue?

```
public Book getSelectedBook() {
}
```

I tried using a if statement but it gave me a error of unreachable code

Comment: How about you show us the attempt that failed, so we can help you improve it, rather than us having to give you all the code from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `indexOfSelected` as a variable, you could set it to -1 to indicate no book was selected.

Then:

```
public Book getSelectedBook() {
    if (indexOfSelected < 0 || indexOfSelected >= books.size()) return null;
    return books.get(indexOfSelected);
}
```

Comment: I would *only* handle a special sentinel (i.e. indexOfSeleced == -1 or NOT_SELECTED) and let the normal [AIOOB]Exception occur in other cases .. (otherwise a returned null could mask other issues, and I prefer to fail soon, except when explicitly being generous in the method contract)